# Why page url ("og:url") appending page file path two times from pageModel meta set in DXA 1.5 Java?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5

Why page url (`og:url`) appending page file path two times from `pageModel` meta set? Do I need to change some config, or what needs to be changed?

EX:  Expected - `/dev/gpt/` but it's coming `/dev/gpt/dev/gpt`

```
<c:forEach var="meta" items="${pageModel.meta.entrySet()}">
    <meta name="${meta.key}" content="${meta.value}">
</c:forEach>

<meta name="og:url" content="https://my-domain/dev/gpt/dev/gpt">
```

Comment: IIRC, this was a bug which has been fixed in a later DXA release, but not sure which one.

Comment: It was only fixed in DXA 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was identified a while ago and is indeed (as Alexey mentions in the comments) fixed in DXA 2.0. If I'm correct the actual fix itself is done in the file [`WebRequestContextImpl.java`](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/develop/dxa-framework/dxa-common-impl/src/main/java/com/sdl/webapp/common/impl/WebRequestContextImpl.java), but a simple comparison of that file will show that quite lot has changed, because the file is refractored for DXA 2.0 in that same commit. You can checkout the entire commit here: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/commit/9a5208debbc477bcb334d4e7cdaab37c1a7e677b#diff-b1f5e76842ed8b1355c59d6f578b087b

I did a quick comparison for the file `WebRequestContextImpl.java` from DXA 1.5 and the current development branch of DXA 2.0, which gives you a slightly better overview of the changes to just that file: https://gist.github.com/bkoopman/cacfa65cbad0d03c0f5e648f006dc9b5/revisions

We are planning the next DXA 2.0 CTP release in a week or so, but the offical DXA 2.0 GA release won't be untill a few months from now (it is currently scheduled around the beginning of Q4 2017).